# Convergence of sets in Probability theory.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory

Assume ${A_n} \to A$ and ${B_n} \to B$, Then I want to prove if it is true that

${A_n} \cup {B_n} \to A \cup B$  and ${A_n} \cap {B_n} \to A \cap B$.

I know that if ${A_n} \to A$,  so $\mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to \infty } \sup {A_n}  = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to \infty } \inf {A_n} = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to \infty } {A_n} = A$.

Comment: How do you define $A_n\to A$ ?

Comment: It is $\mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to \infty } {A_n} = A$

Comment: But how do you define $\lim_{n\to \infty }A_n$ ? Normally it's defined as $\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb N}A_n$ when $A_{n}\subset A_{n+1}$, but there are other way to defined it !

Comment: This depends on whether it is sup or inf, so $\mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to \infty } \inf {A_n} = \bigcup\limits_{n \ge 1} {\bigcap\limits_{k \ge n} {{A_k}} } $ and $\mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to \infty } \sup {A_n} = \bigcap\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {\bigcup\limits_{k = n}^\infty  {{A_k}} } $. I'm using the Resnick book, "A probability path".

Comment: And I can't use $\mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to \infty } {A_n} = \bigcup\limits_{n \in {\rm N}} {{A_n}} $, because I don't have the information if the sequence is monotonous.

Comment: I request you to either accept the answer below or write one yourself and close this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\lim A_n$ exists when $\limsup A_n = \liminf A_n$, and it is equal to either of these quantities.

To show that $A_n \cup B_n \to A \cup B$, we need to show that $\limsup A_n \cup B_n = \liminf A_n \cup B_n$. We assume this true for $A_n$ and $B_n$.

Let $p \in \limsup A_n \cup B_n$. Then, there exists a subsequence $n_k$ such that $p \in A_{n_k} \cup B_{n_k}$ for all $k$. It is clear that at least one of the following happens : infinitely many $A_{n_k}$ contain $p$, or infinitely many $B_{n_k}$ contain $p$. Suppose WLOG that infinitely many $A_{n_k}$ contain $p$, then $p \in \limsup A_n = \liminf A_n$.

However, the definition of $\liminf$ is that there is some $N$ such that $n \geq N \implies p \in A_n$. Hence, this implies that $n \geq N \implies p \in A_n \cup B_n$. From this, it follows that $\lim A_n \cup B_n$ exists. I leave you to show that it is equal to $A \cup B$.

Use a similar argument for intersection.

Comment: But for definition $\mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to \infty } \inf {A_n} \subset \mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to \infty } \sup {A_n}$. So    $\mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to \infty } \inf {A_n} \cup {B_n} \subset \mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to \infty } \sup {A_n} \cup {B_n} = A \cup B$.

Comment: Yes. I have shown that the other way is also true, which is what you  wanted me to show.